# plotting graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, coordinates

I have this points here

x-axis : `0.958` `1.043` `1.907` `0.780` `0.579` `0.003` `0.001` `0.014` `0.007` `0.004`

y-axis : `0.003` `0.001` `0.003` `0.002` `0.001` `0.105` `1.748` `1.839` `1.021` `0.214`

`a vector V1 = [-0.425, 0.977]`

How can i plot all these on 1 graph?

With scales:

`x-axis: 10^-3 until 10^1`

`y-axis: 10^-3 until 10^1`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do a log-log plot. You could do this:

```
>> x=[0.958 1.043 1.907 0.780 0.579 0.003 0.001 0.014 0.007 0.004];
>> y=[0.003 0.001 0.003 0.002 0.001 0.105 1.748 1.839 1.021 0.214];
>> loglog(x,y, '.');
```

Which gives this:

[image]

If you want to also plot the vector you can't plot in log-space (at least on the x-axis) because of the negative x value. Plotting in normal space can be done by:

```
>> x=[0.958 1.043 1.907 0.780 0.579 0.003 0.001 0.014 0.007 0.004];
>> y=[0.003 0.001 0.003 0.002 0.001 0.105 1.748 1.839 1.021 0.214];
>> figure;
>> plot(x, y, '.');
>> hold on;
>> plot([0 -.425], [0 .977]);
```

The results aren't as pretty:

[image]

Comment: I assumed the vector V was defined as the two-tuple (x,y). Is this correct?